# How to access an arraylist after 4 threads are finished

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

i got 4 threads running and ech run increases the size of a global arraylist.But i cant access the resulting arraylist after the threads are finished. Is there a way to get access to the resulting arraylist..or how does it work with threads and resutling datastructures??

```
List<MyObject> head = a.subList(0, 2000);
    List<MyObject> body = a.subList(2001, 5000);
    List<MyObject> body2 =  a.subList(5001, 8000);
    List<MyObject> tail = a.subList(8001, a.size());
    //System.out.println(tail.size());
    createAndRunFirst(head);
    createAndRunFirst(body);
```

these are the calls

and this is the method which is called 4 times..and i need the currCDO arrylist

```
public void algo(List<MyObject>list){
    MyObject a = null;
    MyObject b = null;

    int e=0;
    String curr1="";
    String curr2="";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        a =list.get(i);
        curr1= a.getStreetName();
        if(curr1.contains("-")){
            curr1=curr1.replace("-", " ");
        }

        if(curr1.contains("STRASSE")){
            curr1=curr1.replace("STRASSE", "STR.");
        }

        else{
            curr1=a.getStreetName();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < lotse.size(); j++) {
            b = lotse.get(j);

            curr2=b.getStreetName();
            if(curr2.contains("-")){
                curr2=curr2.replace("-", " ");
            }

            if(curr2.contains("STRASSE")){
                curr2=curr2.replace("STRASSE", "STR.");
            }

            else{
                curr2=b.getStreetName();
            }



            int d = dL.execute(curr1,curr2);

            if(curr1.length()==curr2.length()){
                e=0;
            }
            if(curr1.length()< curr2.length()){
                 e=(curr2.length()*30)/100;
                //System.out.println(d);
            }
            if(curr1.length()> curr2.length()){
                 e=(curr1.length()*30)/100;
                //System.out.println(d);
            }

            if(d<e && a.getPcode().contains(b.getPcode())){
                int x=a.getInstituteName().length();
                int y=b.getInstituteName().length();

                if(x<y){

                    currCDO.add(a);


                }
                if(y<x){

                    currCDO.add(a);

                if(x==y){

                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                break;}else{

                    //System.out.println(a.getInstituteName()+"******");
                    restCDO.add(a);
                }
            }//System.out.println(currCDO.size() +"*****");
        }
        }

}

public void createAndRunFirst(final List<CrawlerDataObject> list) {
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run(){
              algo(list);

          }

       });
       thread.start();

    }
```

Comment: Add some code please? What have you tried? We have no idea how to solve your problem if we don't even know what code is causing it

Comment: In other words,...   You say, " i cant access the resulting arraylist."  How do you _know_ you can't access it?  Where is your code that tries to access it?  What did you expect it to do (preferably, what did you expect it to _print_)?  What did it actually do/print instead?

Comment: subList creates a shallow copy, so changes made to objects in each subList should show up to the main list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming currCDO is global, are you waiting for all the threads to finish?

You might want to consider building an output list for each thread and then concactenating them at the end.  This would avoid locking.  You could use a threadsafe list too, but that might be slower.  I don't know c# specifically, but I assume there are threadsafe lists.

```
int i0 = 0;
int c = a.size()/cThread;
new List<MyObject>()[cThread];
for (int iThread=0 ; iThread<cThread ; ++iThread, i0+=c) {
    createAndRunFirst(a.subList(i0, i0 + c - 1), aOut[iThread]);
}

waitForAllThreads();  // i don't know the c# for this

for (int iThread=0 ; iThread<cThread ; ++iThread) {
    currCDO += aOut[iThread];
}


public void createAndRunFirst(final List<CrawlerDataObject> list, List<CrawlerDataObject> out) {
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run(){
          algo(list, out);

      }

   });

public void algo(List<MyObject> list, List<MyObject> currCDO) {
}
```